# Помогите разобраться с функциями

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть две функции: `Listo1()` и `Listo2()`. Каждая содержит свой список. Вопрос: Почему Listo1 благополучно возвращает свой список, в то время как Listo2 - нет?

```
def Listo1():
    a = []
    a.extend([1,2,3])
    return a

Listo1()

def Listo2():
    a = []
    for i in range(5):
        a.append(lambda x, i=i: i ** x)
    return a

Listo2()(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лямбда - это функция, а не значение.

```
func = lambda x, i: i ** x

def Listo2():
    a = []
    for i in range(5):
        a.append(func(5, i))
    return a

print(Listo2())
```